# Repeating code for same operation of different datatypes, Express(nodejs) app with mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, restful-url

I am creating an Express rest API that connects to a MongoDB with mongoose. The database has several different datatypes: `User`, `Book`, `Food` and so on. As I am writing endpoints and function for these datatypes. I realized that I am repeating a lot of the same code, for example, for the code below:

```
// Book.js
import Book from './models/Book'

function deleteById (req, res, next) {
  Book.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      let error = new Error('Failed to delete an book in database')
      error.statusCode = 500
      return next(error)
    }
    res.json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Book deleted successfully'
    })
  })
}
```

I can just change `Book` to `User` or `Food` and the same code can be used. Which results in a lot of repeating code that looks like this:

```
// Food.js
import Food from './models/Food'

function deleteById (req, res, next) {
  Food.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      let error = new Error('Failed to delete an food in database')
      error.statusCode = 500
      return next(error)
    }
    res.json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Food deleted successfully'
    })
  })
}
```

So I was wondering if there is a way to generate the functions so that I don't need to repeat the code for the `deleteById` function for each type of data. What would be the best practice? Or is it a bad practice to try to generate the functions and repeating is necessary?

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: One could also fairly argue that having both `.findByIdAndRemove()` as well as `deleteById()` is a fair amount of unnecessary duplication, and born out of some fairly outmoded concepts in what people get taught. But you can indeed do something like `conn.model('User').findByIdAndRemove(id)`, so that's one way of passing in, or alternately if you have another way to pass in the resolved model token as opposed to the "string" of the name, then you could do that as well. There are plenty of DRY approaches you can take, and "best practice" is really usually what actually "works best for you".

Comment: You are right about the duplication, the wrapper here is just to take care of the error tracking and response sending. For best practice, I am looking for something like a standard or the recommended way. For example, express best practice for error handling is to call `next(err)` as described on the official website. But one could argue that doing `res.json()` in every error situation works best for him, but in this case, it would not be a best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found the best way to be using a class constructor and pass in datatype as a variable:

```
class BaseController {
  constructor (type, name) {
    if (!type || !access) {
      throw new Error('Must define datatype')
    }
    this.datatype = type
    this.name = name
    this.deleteById = this.deleteById.bind(this)
  }

  deleteById (req, res, next) {
    let name = this.name
    this.datatype.findByIdAndRemove(id, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        let error = new Error(`Failed to delete ${name} in database`)
        error.statusCode = 500
        return next(error)
      }

      res.json({
        success: true,
        message: `${name} deleted successfully`
      })
    })
  }
}
```

And in the router file, we can just call

```
const food = new BaseController(Food, 'Food')
router.get('/food/delete/:id', food.deleteById)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a delete middleware. In the below code I pass the model delete `function` as `argument` and I return a middleware. In that middleware function I call the delete `function` that came dynamically.

```
var deleteMiddleWare = function(deleteByIdFunc, name) {

    var deleteId = req.params.id;

    if (!deleteId)
        res.json({
            success: false,
            message: `Please provide ${name} id.`
        })

    return function(req, res, next) {

        deleteByIdFunc(req.params.id, function(err) {

            if (err) {
                let error = new Error(`Failed to delete ${name} in database`)
                error.statusCode = 500
                return next(error)
            }
            res.json({
                success: true,
                message: `${name} deleted successfully`
            })

        })

    }
}

router.get(/user/delete /: id, deleteMiddleWare(User.deleteById, 'User'))
router.get(/food/delete /: id, deleteMiddleWare(Food.deleteById, 'Food'))
```

Comment: This is actually really smart, I really like it.